# ThreadLocal behaviour on session timeout

Tags: spring, session, spring-security, thread-local-storage

I am working on a Java based web-app and we use ThreadLocal to keep a track of the current logged in user. Now, normally it works perfectly fine. But, whenever there is a session timeout, and the system tries to access the variable (from ThreadLocal data), it gives random value (value of some other logged in user). Ideally it should have returned a null value. I am confused as to what's happening here.

Comment: This is a *broken* design. Threads (and TLS) are not related to sessions - *multiple requests and multiple sessions may run on the same thread and share the same TLS!!!*. I would expect that it's just luck the TLS even "works" before the logout.

Comment: OK, so you are saying that ThreadLocal variables aren't individual to a session? If so, can you give me a li'l details about thread local functionality for a web-app.

Comment: 1. We are only invalidating session and not doing any change to the thread local variable.
2. Even though we don't set it to null, but still why would it give value of other logged in user?

Comment: Why are you not using `SecurityContextHolder` to get the currently logged user?

Comment: @LaurentG Actually, I am not sure why it's been implemented this way. The original product dev team has been changed altogether, so the exact reason for using this approach is not known. Actually I was hoping to fix it with minimum changes required, so wanted to know in more details about the working of `ThreadLocal api`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threads are pooled, so you need to ensure to clear the ThreadLocal out for each request. If you were doing this in a Filter it might look something like this:

```
private static final ThreadLocal<String> CONTEXT = new ThreadLocal<String>();

public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

    try {
        CONTEXT.set(userName);
        chain.doFilter(req,res);
    } finally {
        CONTEXT.remove();
    }
}
```

Otherwise what might happen is:

- UserA logs in and is associated to ThreadA (UserA is in the context)
- UserB logs in and is associated to ThreadB (UserB is in the context)
- UserA's session times out and no longer has user information associated to his session
- UserA uses ThreadB and then since ThreadB is used again, it appears UserB is in the context)

Not only is this a security issue, but it is also a memory leak. While only one per Thread that is populated with a user seems pretty small it can add up. Additionally, if the object placed in the ThreadLocal is an Object that the type belongs to the war's ClassLoader you will have a large [PermGen leak](http://frankkieviet.blogspot.com/2006/10/how-to-fix-dreaded-permgen-space.html) that leaks the entire contents of your war each time your application is undeployed/deployed without restarting your application server.

@LaurentG is correct that the approach to use with Spring Security is to use the SecurityContextHolder. You can see that the SecurityContextPersistenceFilter ensures the SecurityContext [gets cleared out](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/context/SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java#L92) in a finally block.

Comment: Thanks all for helping out. I am marking this as the answer, as it explains everything in complete details. This filter approach seems to be good, will give it a try.